# Java Paint Application thorws NullPointer when clearing the drawing surface

Tags: java, graphics2d, awt-eventqueue

My problem is the following: i'm trying to make a paint application in java. I get this error code:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at areacalc.DrawArea.clear(Form.java:67)
    at areacalc.DrawArea.mouseMoved(Form.java:115)
```

when i'm clearing the drawing surface.

Here is my code, could you please help me to avoid the null pointer? Where should i place the event handlers to not to get null pointer?

Thank you so much!
Regards, Stanley.

package areacalc;

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class DrawArea extends JComponent implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{   
    private Image image;
    private Graphics2D g2;        
    private int currentX, currentY, oldX, oldY, X, Y;
    private ArrayList<Integer[]> points = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
    private boolean stopped = false;
    public boolean crtl_pressed = false;

    public DrawArea()
    {   
        setDoubleBuffered(false);       
        initEventHandlers();
    }

    public void initEventHandlers()
    {
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public double length(int x1, int x2)
    {
        return Math.abs(x1-x2);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        //System.out.println("paintComponent");

        if (image == null)
        {
            image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
            g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            clear();            
        }

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); 
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        g2.setPaint(Color.black);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
    {       
    if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1&&(!stopped))
      {
          oldX = e.getX();
          oldY = e.getY();

          if((currentX!=oldX)&&(currentY!=oldY)&&(currentX!=0)&&(currentY!=0))
          {
              g2.setPaint(Color.green);
              Integer i[] = { currentX, currentY, e.getX(), e.getY() };
              points.add(i);
              g2.drawLine(currentX, currentY, e.getX(), e.getY());
              repaint();
          }
      }
      else if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3&&points.size()>0)           
      {
          g2.setPaint(Color.green);
          g2.drawLine(currentX, currentY, e.getX(), e.getY());

          if(points.size()>0)
                {
                    Integer i[] = points.get(0);
                    g2.drawLine(e.getX(), e.getY(), i[0], i[1]);
                }

          repaint();
          stopped = true;
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if((!stopped))
        {               
            //label.setText(e.getX() + ";" + e.getY());

            currentX = oldX;
            currentY = oldY;

            clear();    

            for(int j = 0; j < points.size(); j++)
            {
                g2.setPaint(Color.green);
                Integer i[] = points.get(j);
                g2.drawLine(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3]);
                repaint();
            }

            if((currentX!=0)&&(currentY!=0))
            {
                g2.setPaint(Color.yellow);

                if(!crtl_pressed)
                {
                    if(points.size()>0)
                    {
                        Integer i[] = points.get(0);
                        g2.drawLine(e.getX(), e.getY(), i[0], i[1]);
                    }

                    g2.drawLine(currentX, currentY, e.getX(), e.getY());
                }                       
                else
                {
                    if(length(currentX, e.getX())>=length(currentY, e.getY()))
                    {
                        if(points.size()>0)
                        {
                            Integer i[] = points.get(0);
                            g2.drawLine(e.getX(), currentY, i[0], i[1]);

                        }

                        g2.drawLine(currentX, currentY, e.getX(), currentY);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(points.size()>0)
                        {
                            Integer i[] = points.get(0);
                            g2.drawLine(currentX, e.getY(), i[0], i[1]);
                        }                           

                        g2.drawLine(currentX, currentY, currentX, e.getY());
                    }
                }                       

                repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
}

public class Form extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    public Form() 
    {
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() 
    {    
        setTitle("Area Calculator");
        setSize(600, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        Container content = getContentPane();
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        DrawArea drawArea = new DrawArea();
        content.add(drawArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        addKeyListener(
            new KeyAdapter()
            {
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
                {
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                        //drawArea.crtl_pressed = true;
                }

                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
                {
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                        //drawArea.crtl_pressed = false;
                }
        });
    }

    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) 
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setPaint(Color.blue);

        g2d.drawLine(20, 20, 500, 500);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        paintComponent(g);
        doDrawing(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `clear()` is called before `paintComponent()`, the variable g2 is not initialized.

You could initialize your g2 instance in the constructor, but I'm not sure if this works for you because you need the size of the window.

Another option is to insert

```
if (g2 == null) return;
```

as first line for `clear`.

It seems that this is kind of a double buffering implementation. I'm sure Google will help you finding good examples for alternative implementations without this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! The return solved the problem. :)